# Understanding CSS grid and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

https://codepen.io/masm/pen/MxWBEB

Hello there, 
I am trying to create a basic, responsive layout using CSS Grid and Flexbox. However I'm coming across some issues with the header. I don't full understand why the logo and nav aren't spanning across the 960px width.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hd">
  <div class="container">
    <div class"ct">
      <div class="logo">
        Logo
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#">one</a>
        <a href="#">two</a>
        <a href="#">three</a>
        <a href="#">four</a>
        <a href="#">five</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container { 
  width: 960px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-areas: "top top"
    "main side"
}

.ct { 
  grid-area: top;
}

.logo { 
  background: #ddd;
}

.nav { 
  background: #ddf; 
}
```

Secondly, I am trying to make it so that the logo and nav are side by side. My idea was to set .ct to display:flex, however it does not work.

```
.ct { 
  grid-area: top;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
}
```

Lastly, I want the background colors of the header to span the full width of the page, and the content (logo, nav, main, side) to take up no more than the 960px width, which is why I added a container in between the #hd and #main divs. My question here is, is this a good approach?

Comment: Fixed the typo in `class"ct"` - it was correct in the codepen linked by the OP...

Comment: @kukkuz it wasn't correct .. unfortunately the codepen isn't static and will change if the OP apply changes (unlike jsfiddle) so the OP already fixed the codepen based on the accepted answer. We should revert the edit and close the question as typo issue

Comment: Good eye, I missed that man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues I have noted in your code are the following,

you forgot to add "=" before the class name. ie " "
then you put "flex-direction: column;"

Please check the following fiddle. Hope that's what you are looking for

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waf4vr0h/1/)

```
.ct { 
 grid-area: top;
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: row; 
}
```

Comment: I feel so silly now--thank you! Also noted the use of flex-grow. I'm so new to flexbox I didn't know about the property.
Thank you everyone as well!

Answer (score 0):

For side by side, you need to place them row-wise and in the center align the content of the div vertically, Also give some predefined height to it:

```
.ct{
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow: row;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `flex-direction: column;` and there is no `=` after class `ct`

```
<div class="ct">
```

```css
#hd { 
background: #444;
}

.container { 
  width: 960px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-areas: "top top"
    "main side"
}

.ct { 
  grid-area: top;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
}

.logo { 
  background: #ddd;
}

.nav { 
  background: #ddf; 
}

.main {
  background: #ee0099; 
  grid-area: main;
}

.side { 
  background: #efefef; 
  grid-area: side;
}

.ct { 
  grid-area: top;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
}
```

```html
<div id="hd">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ct">
      <div class="logo">
        Logo
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#">one</a>
        <a href="#">two</a>
        <a href="#">three</a>
        <a href="#">four</a>
        <a href="#">five</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mn">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
      <p>hello</p>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```